# Corrupted inbox file for thunderbird after an update

Tags: thunderbird

This morning my Thunderbird client had an automatic update, after it the program started but the inbox was completely free with 0 messages. New messages began to arrive but all old messages were lost.

I check in the local files of Thunderbird's profile and the Inbox file was very big (2.9GB) as expected, but opening Thunderbird there was only few messages in the inbox.

I had to recover the Inbox file from a backup and now everything works, but what happend? Why a so big file with only few message?

Answer (score 0):

I use Thunderbird as my e-mail client, and I've never had a problem with updates. Perhaps your huge Inbox file was the problem, especially if you're using a 32-bit version.

Three things to try **after backing up**:-

1. Right-click `Inbox` and select `Compact`, then make sure your messages are intact and check in the mail folder that `Inbox` is now a realistic size.
2. Create a temporary mail folder and move all the `Inbox` messages to it, then compact `Inbox` and check in the mail directory that the size of `Inbox` is now zero, with a couple of KB in `Inbox.msf`, and finally move the messages back from the temporary folder and delete it.

   - If `Inbox` is still a silly size, empty it with `:>Inbox` in the mail directory, remove any `Inbox.sbd` subdirectory, then in Thunderbird right-click and select `Properties` and press the `Repair` button, before moving the messages back.
3. Install `ImportExportTools`, then right-click `Inbox` and select `ImportExportTools` -> `Export all messages in the folder` -> `EML format`, clear `Inbox` as in the note to (2) above, then then right-click `Inbox` and select `ImportExportTools` -> `Import all messages from a directory` -> `also from its subdirectories` - the messages will be in a time-stamped directory `Limbo_YYYYMMDD-hhmm/messages/` within the directory you selected for export.

At least one of these measures should successfully retrieve your `Inbox` in a reasonably-sized folder. Note that `Inbox.sbd` will exist if you have subfolders within `Inbox` and it will be re-created when you copy or import the messages again.

Comment: This Thunderbird is installed in Windows XP SO, so I think this is 32bit. Do you think I should reorganize my messages into more folders?

Comment: This will certainly help, especially if `Inbox` has very large subfolders. I prefer to move all received and sent e-mails into different folders outside `Inbox`, but I use POP3: different considerations may apply if you use IMAP, but I have never used this in anger, so I'm not sure what the best organisation might be. Whatever else, I would certainly recommend keeping e-mail folders under 1GB. (For the record, I collect e-mails from a number of different servers, not all of which support IMAP, hence my use of POP3.)